# Why Energy in Restricted Boltzmann Machine?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

In Restricted Boltzmann Machine (RBM), we define the energy function $E(\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{h}; \, \mathbf{W}, \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})$.

- $\mathbf{v}$ is visible unit
- $\mathbf{h}$ is hidden unit
- $\mathbf{W}$ is the connection matrix between $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{h}$
- $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}$ are the bias vector for visible and hidden units

And the aim is to learn the parameter $\mathbf{W}$, $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$. from the training sample.

**My question:**  What is the intuition behind this setup? In particular, the concept of energy function $E$ is not found in other machine learning methods (e.g. ANN, CNN ...etc).

I know that RBM is related to statistical mechanics in Physics (e.g. Ising Model and Inverse Ising Problem), but I don't really understand why such concept is useful in machine learning.

Related paper: [Restricted Boltzmann Machines for Collaborative Filtering](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1273596)

Thanks.

Comment: Which papers have you read?  Please add the citations to your question.

Comment: I have edited the question with a paper added.

Comment: Originates from [Sherrington–Kirkpatrick model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_glass#Sherrington–Kirkpatrick_model)

Answer (score 1):

Artificial neural networks can be written as energy-based models.  See LeCun, Yann, et al. "A tutorial on energy-based learning." Predicting structured data 1.0 (2006).

The energy-based model framework is just a convenient, intuitive way of thinking about models.

Comment: On p.11 of the paper (Sec. 2.2: Examples of Loss Functions), it stats that the loss function can be chosen simply as the energy function -- Eqn. (6). Does it mean that ANN can be regarded as EBM?

Comment: @K_inverse no...